# Azure pipeline shows an error but it is not

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure pipeline with a SSH command step. I need to run command `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate app` from a remote machine.

Command is executed and it works fine, but for some reason Azure says it exited with error. This is the output of the pipeline task:

> Trying to establish an SSH connection to ***@**.***.**.**:**
> Successfully connected.
>
> chmod +x ./sshscript_b9ea4087-4f62-4208-a57f-5d03fdb91adf
>
> ./sshscript_b9ea4087-4f62-4208-a57f-5d03fdb91adf
>
> ##[error]Recreating my-app ...
>
> ##[error]Recreating my-app ... done
>
> ##[error]Command failed with errors on remote machine.
>
> Finishing: Release latest version

Of ourse, my pipeline terminates with error. However, the task has been done properly. Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm guessing that the exit code from the ./sshscript...  is non-zero?  (or whatever the value is to trigger an 'error' in the calling script)  (just a guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's happening but I found a workaround. I used this command:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate app &>/dev/null ; echo $?
```

to be sure that exit code is 0. It works fine.